# What level of speed is required to make the player twice as fast?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In minecraft, effects can make the player run faster than their normal maximum sprinting speed.

What level of speed is required to make the player twice as fast as normal?

I don't think that speed 2 makes you twice as fast, even though it's name would imply such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Wiki for Speed](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Status_effect#Speed):

> Increases walking speed by 20% × level. Expands field of view (FOV) accordingly.

Therefore, to achieve double the speed, you would need **Speed 5** to reach 100% more than the normal rate.  You can use the `/effect` command to obtain this.